# Show hide icon in a Listview

Tags: c#, uwp

Suppose I Have a listview with 10 ListViewItems each of which has other nested UIElements. Each ListViewItem has a nested  AppBarButton.
By default, the AppBarButton visibility is set to collapsed in a LisViewItem. I want the AppBarButton to be visible when a user hovers over a ListViewItem.

The ListViewItem has  PointerEntered="ListviewEnter", PointerExited="ListviewExit" events handlers attached to it.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind people}">   
           <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
                      Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">

                    <ListViewItem 
                        PointerEntered="ListviewEnter"
                        PointerExited="ListviewExit"
                        Background="LightBlue">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind age}"/>
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" 
                                    BorderBrush="Green" 
                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                <AppBarButton 
                                   x:Name="ssss"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                                    Icon="Delete" 
                                               Label="Delete" 
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </Border>

                        </Grid>


                    </ListViewItem>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property in your Person class to bind the Visibility of AppBarButton.When hovers over a ListViewItem,set the property true to show the AppBarButton.

**Person class:**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {​
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };​
        public String name ...;​
        public String age ...;​
        private bool isShow = false;​
        public bool IsShow​
        {​
            get { return isShow; }​
            set​
            {​
                isShow = value;​
                this.OnPropertyChanged();​
            }​
        }​
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)​
        {​
            // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.​
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));​
        }​
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<AppBarButton  Visibility="{x:Bind IsShow,Mode=OneWay}"​ Icon="Delete" ​ Label="Delete" ​ HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

**Code-behind:**

When trigger the ListViewEnter and ListViewExit events,you can get the Person class from it and change the IsShow property to control the Visibility of AppBarButton.

```
private void ListviewEnter(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {​
            ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem;​
            Person p = item.DataContext as Person;​
            p.IsShow = true;​
        }​
​
        private void ListviewExit(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)​
        {​
            ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem;​
            Person p = item.DataContext as Person;​
            p.IsShow = false;​
​
        }
```

Comment: Very simple and intuitive solution. Solved my issue tnx.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT  It was really helpful for me, for example.  Was searching a way for doing hover effect over listviewitem’s datatemplates and now I found it!  Many thanks.